# Windows command prompt start from certain directory

Tags: windows, command-line, console, command-prompt

I have a .bat file

and in the file something like this

```
d:
cd Doc
cd bestFolder
```

The problem is when I start the bat file with double click the console is prompted but in just few moments it is gone :(

How can I make a bat file that will start the command promt at some specific directory ?

NOTE: I want to be able to input commands after the console is show I do not want the console to be hidden in just few moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line `cmd` at the end of your batch file.

```
@echo off    
d:
cd Doc
cd bestFolder
REM <any other commands you want to run>
cmd
```

That will execute the commands and **prevent your command window closing**.

Answer (score 0):

You do that by creating a shortcut to cmd.exe and editing the properties of the shortcut. One of the properties deals with the initial current directory.